# What will a "single variable as a statement" do?

Tags: c++

Below is the C++ function in a project I took over lately. Each of the last two statements is just a variable, containing no assignment. What will such kind of statement do? Lately, I saw such kinds of statements usually.

```
__fastcall TCardActionArea::TCardActionArea(TComponent* Owner)
:TArea(Owner,"CardActionArea")
{
    // Get the thread id
    ThreadId = std::__threadid();
    
    this->Visible= false;
    m_pBackGroundPicture = NULL;
    m_pActionButtonMap.clear();
    m_ActionsButtonDisplayed.clear();
    
    m_changecnt = 0;
    m_isNextbtn = true;
    m_PictureParamPath1;
    m_PictureParamPath2;
}
```

Comment: it wont do anything and will produce a warning to that effect in [most compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/heanaenKf)

Comment: Doesn't do anything. Maybe it's used to convey "yes I'm intentionally keeping this variable uninitialized".

Comment: Generate warnings to catch your eye. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, these statements do not do anything, and it is definitely not a common practice to write them.

Maybe the author just wanted to explicitly note that they do not need to assign any values to these members (although a comment would do better).

Maybe this is some hack for a particular compiler to prevent some optimization (e.g. to prevent the member from being optimized away), but it would be a very slippery hack that may not work on a next compiler version.

Maybe the author intended to assign something to these variables and just forgot to do this, so this may be a bug.

Or maybe the author just had some kind of template, e.g. listing all the members to make sure they did not forgot anything, and just kept the parts of template they did not need to change.

Comment: It's a little strange that I saw such statements kind of often in this newly assigned project. It's from French originally and is maintained by Taiwanese engineers now.

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan obviously it is some perk of the author of the code. It's not strange that after switching to a new codebase you see new, maybe unusual or strange, patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've seen statements like this used was to silence compiler warnings about unreferenced variables (usually function arguments). I haven't checked whether MSVC (which features of this code lead me to believe was used, at least originally) issues such warnings about unused members, although that does seem a stretch as it would only work in some whole-code analysis mode.